# How can I color a graph (vertices and edges) with excel data?

Tags: css, excel

I'm have an excel file with mostly 0's and 1's and I want to use this information to color the vertices and edges of a graph. So like if a cell is 0, color the edge gray, but if the cell is 1, color it blue. And similarly for vertices.

Can anyone give me a suggestion for how to go about this? What should I use to make the graph? And how do I tell it how to color it?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Try using D3 graph. Visit https://d3js.org/ 
D3 uses javascript language. You can refer to multiple graphs. 
Even you can take input data from excel file to create dynamic graphs.
You can refer to D3 network graph to understand how to change colour of vertex and edges of graph from given data http://christophergandrud.github.io/d3Network/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the x and y values you can plot them directly on a worksheet.  The following is an example that randomly generates x and y coordinates for 5 points.  A small filled circle is drawn at each point.  A line is drawn between the previous and the next point forming a closed loop.

To demonstrate how you can select the line colors I alternately color them gray and blue to give you an idea of how to selectively color them based on some other criteria.

vbBlue is one of a preset color pallet (see this [link](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm)) which is why it doesn't have to be declared - unlike vbGray.

```
Option Explicit


Sub drawALine(xFrm As Double, yFrm As Double, xTo As Double, yTo As Double, c As Long)
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(xFrm, yFrm, xTo, yTo).Line
    .DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot
    .ForeColor.RGB = c
  End With
End Sub


Sub drawNode(r As Double, x As Double, y As Double, c As Long)
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, x - r / 2, y - r / 2, r, r)
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = c
  End With
End Sub


Sub ConnectedOverLappingLoop()
  Dim xMax As Double, yMax As Double, x1 As Double, y1 As Double
  Dim xFrm As Double, yFrm As Double, xTo As Double, yTo As Double
  Dim radius As Double
  Dim vbGray As Long, clr As Long

  xMax = 200
  yMax = 200
  radius = 5
  vbGray = RGB(150, 150, 150)

  xFrm = Rnd() * xMax
  yFrm = Rnd() * yMax
  x1 = xFrm
  y1 = yFrm
  clr = vbBlue

  drawNode radius, x1, y1, vbBlue

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To 5:
    xTo = Rnd() * xMax
    yTo = Rnd() * yMax

    drawNode radius, xTo, yTo, vbBlue
    drawALine xFrm, yFrm, xTo, yTo, clr
    xFrm = xTo
    yFrm = yTo

    If clr = vbBlue Then
       clr = vbGray
    Else
       clr = vbBlue
    End If

  Next
  drawALine xFrm, yFrm, x1, y1, clr

End Sub
```